# WPF: How to close Dialog on button click

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, dialog, modal-dialog

So I have a editable ViewModel where I wan't it only to be editable through a Dialog window.

Normally the ViewModels view only shows the data but you could press a Edit button which opens up a new Xaml window by calling window.showDialog(). The window takes in the viewModel as it's DataContext, exposes it's properties as editable and has the Save and Cancel commands bound to buttons.

It all works fine but I'm having some problems with this.

Firstly the save command works but it doesn't close the dialog. Secondly it kind of breaks the MVVM because the VM has to know of the EditDialog view to create it.

Also what happens when I click the X close button. I know a Dialog would normally return false as DialogResult but here I'm not handling results.

Has anyone done something similar but elegantly using MVVM?

**EDIT**

I also noticed that if I use .ShowDialog I can't edit anything even if I expose as TextBoxes. Is this because of how Modal Dialogs are supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways here:

1) `EditorVM` doesn't know anything about dialog. In this case I would leave this VM as a simple editor which exposes properties but has no `SaveCommand`. Then `Save` button should be injected from outside, somewhere where you open a dialog. Then after closing dialog you check whether dialog was closed using `Save` button or it was closed using `Cancel` button. Then code which opened a dialog should check returned result and invoke `Save` method if dialog was closed with `Save` button. With this approach you will have to make your dialog a little bit more complicated - you will have to insert `Save` and `Cancel` buttons from `ShowDialog` methods instead of pulling them as part of `ViewModel` which will be displayed. But this approach allows isolating your `EditorVM` from any dialog-specific behaviors.

2) `EditorVM` assumes that it was opened in dialog and in `Save` command handler it saves it's content and closes the dialog. In order to access dialog's functionality, I'm usually using some kind of `IWindowManager` service which handles all opened windows and can determine which dialog contains which viewModel and can close them accordingly. Basically this `IWindowManager` service has method like `void CloseDialog(object ViewModel);`.

Comment: Ok I'm not getting solution 1 completely. Where do you open up the dialog then? Also I'm not sure I'll be willing to add a whole IWindowManager when I'm only going to have 1 Modal at most open in addition to app window. Thanks for input.

Comment: @Ingó, I have `IWindowManager` even though we also have only one modal window. The reason to have this service is isolation of your ViewModels from completely `View`-related code (dialog windows). In first scenario I would open dialog using `IWindowManager` from some outer ViewModel. Let's say it is some viewModel which has `EditCommand`. This command should create `EditorViewModel` and open it in dialog.

Comment: I'm considering this, but this would mean having to add yet another service into the ViewModel. Is it getting bloated with services not a problem? If I could let the container handle it it would be no problem but the Model is one of the things I add so I can't do a container resolve.

Comment: @Ingó, I have all my `ViewModels` injected. Is it a problem to resolve a viewmodel if it has a model parameter in constructor?

Comment: Well I would think so as they are created from DataContext, at least I'm not sure how a Container would handle that. Do you have an example? And perhaps an example of a WindowManager class?

Comment: Well, if your viewModels/models take anything from DataContext then something is definitely wrong there. DataContext is completely `View`-related concept while in MVVM models and viewModels should be isolated from `Views`